# Devil's pool safety at Victoria Falls

Tags: safety, adventure, swimming, zimbabwe, victoria-falls

The [Devil's pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_Falls#Tourism_in_recent_years) is a natural pool on the edge of Victoria falls you can swim in during certain months (I saw people doing last September).

[image: public domain image from linked wikipedia article]
<sup>Image is in public domain. Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tourists_swimming_at_Victoria_Falls.jpg).</sup>

Firstly, I haven't found clear dates on when it is safe to do it (just low water level somewhere from Sept to Jan).

Secondly, What is actually involved in getting to and from the pools?

Thirdly, any figures on reported deaths?

Comment: I'm sorta glad it wasn't a thing when I was there. Because I'd totally have to have done it.

Comment: Make sure to pay the guy who holds your feet over the edge half before and half after ;)

Comment: I'm sure I could show him a pretty big tip that would be his if I came back in one place?

Comment: I didn't ask about crocodiles probably should have.

Comment: Devils pools was not an option the water was super fast. i managed to stick my foot in the water about 10m from the falls on the zambian side with someone holding me, and i felt like i was going to get pulled in.

Comment: They average about one a year.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There can't be any exact dates for when it's safe because that depends on the (highly variable) water level in the river, which depends on rainfalls.

Getting there requires taking a boat, a short rocky hike and swimming through a safe part of the river before you get to the pool itself (source: a TV show I saw). You should only do it as a guided tour, in any case. The operators will decide when the water level is safe.

Here's a [Zimbabwean newspaper article](http://www.newzimbabwe.com/news-1052-Tour%20guide%20in%20Vic%20Falls%20plunge/news.aspx) about the death of a tour guide who was rescuing a tourist. It says "Locals say deaths at the site are rare, occurring at the rate of one death every year". Apparently this includes guides as well as tourists - and some tourists take really foolish risks.

Comment: The reason for asking about dates as some sites had very narrow fields.

Answer (score 7):

The reason the dates vary is because high water season varies.  Guides won't take people when the water levels are too high, because they have to take it too.

There's a really [good blog post on this](http://www.reclaimingmyfuture.com/jumping-into-the-devils-pool-victoria-falls/) which details:

- the steps involved getting there (boat ride, pics of the rocky walk, and the jump you need to do to get in
- tips on how to manage it (any girls you are with you may wish to warn about the effects of the strong current on their items of clothing...
- several fantastic photos describing the entire process
- It's probably necessarily to be able to swim.

...I really want to go back to Zambia now.